# Excel: Decomposing numbers into sum of smaller numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a real world use case: I have a home gym with different weighting disks (1.25 kg, 5 kg, 10 kg etc).

I have created an excel spreadsheet that calculates the weight that i should lift per exercise, as an example:

[image: series for first exercise]

My question is: how can I get Excel to automatically decompose each cell into the appropiate disks that I should put on the bar? This is limited by the number of disks per disks weight (I don't have an infinite amount of 1 kg disks)

Example:

On the first cell we have 55 (kg). Since I have 2 disks of 25 kg at home and multiple 5 kg disks, I would like Excel to output `25x2 + 5`.

`15x2 + 10x2 + 2.5x2` would also work but it's much more inefficient, so what I'd like to get is the solution with the least amount of different disks.

Comment: Obviously, a detailed solution can't be offered without knowledge of the denominations of the weights you do have. Add this detail to your question. You should further amend your question to give an idea of what you want to do with any overhang. For example, if the desired total is 13.5 and you have weights of 1 and 5 you wouldn't be able to put equal weights on both sides and you would be left with 0.5kg unless you want to upgrade to a total of 14 or perhaps 12, if weights are to be both equal and available.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `MOD()` and `QUOTIENT()` functions and set up a nested `IF` statement with the various weights you have available.

Eg, using your example with "weight" to be made with 25 and 5 kg weights, something like

```vb
=QUOTIENT(Weight,25) & " 25 kg weights" & IF(MOD(Weight,25)>0," and " & QUOTIENT(MOD(Weight,25),5) & " 5 kg weights ","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link with several solutions for your problem.
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3557-excel-find-all-combinations-that-equal-given-sum.html
You can get there a pure Excel formula solution, Solver Add-In, or VBA. Comment if you need help adapting them.
Post your Excel file if you need more help.